# Mysql Restore - ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 30908: Access denied DEFINER issue

Tags: mysql, restore, mysqldump

Im trying to restore the database dump which has the DEFINER=`test`@`%`.

> Backup file is 50GB.
>
> OS - CentOS 7.5

While restoring this, I got the below error.

```
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 30908: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

The line 30908 is,

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` PROCEDURE `myprod`(IN id INT)
```

So I tried to remove the definer using perl.

```
perl -p -i.bak -e "s/DEFINER=\`\w.*\`@\`\d[0-3].*[0-3]\`//g" my_dump_file.sql
```

Its executed, but after that also, I got the same issue and its not changed in file.

Then I tried,

```
sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' < my_dump_file.sql > my_dump_file.new
```

This is also executed, and tried to restore my_dump_file.new but still same issue on the same line.

Then finally I tried to create an user on the MySQL.

```
create user `test`@`%` identified by 'test';
grant all on *.* to `test`@`%`;
flush privileges;
```

Again, Im getting the same issue.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r -e 's/DEFINER\s*=\s*\S+//'
```

Notes:

`-r` : better syntax

`\s` : any whitespace (eg, tabs, too)

`\S` : non-space

(I tested on Ubuntu, not CentOS.)